After upgrading Kubuntu from version 22.04 to 24.04 (kernel from 5.15 to 6.8), my Dell XPS 15 7590 laptop only boots with the 'nomodeset' parameter
I'm facing a frustrating issue with my Dell XPS 15 7590 after upgrading to Kubuntu 24.04 with kernel 6.8. The system won't boot normally and gets stuck during the boot process, but it does boot successfully if I use the nomodeset parameter in Grub. Here is the configuration from my /etc/default/grub:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1 i915.enable_rc6=1 i915.enable_fbc=1 i915.enable_psr=1"

I tried uncommenting the other lines one by one, but the system only boots with the first configuration. The problem is that with 'nomodeset', my system doesn't recognize my second monitor, which I need for work.
Here's a summary of my situation:

Laptop Model: Dell XPS 15 7590
Graphics: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
OS: Kubuntu 24.04 with kernel 6.8

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions on how to resolve this while still being able to use my second monitor, I would greatly appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance for your support!

What is the full kernel number of the kernel in use? It may work if you move down 1 kernel version. Example 6.8.41 move down to 6.8.35, these are just examples.

Did you boot the Kubuntu 24.04 LTS ISO in live mode and test it on your hardware before upgrade (I gather you did;' especially since the upgrade from 22.04 isn't yet deemed stable) as you don't mention how that testing showed it worked.  If it worked in that environment, I'd expect it to work on your upgraded system too (assuming you read the caveats on upgrade & none of them applied; sorry I've not looked for your hardware, but I assume you did; ie. release notes, release status tracking etc)

"What is the full kernel number of the kernel in use?"
It's a 6.8.0-35-generic

"Did you boot the Kubuntu 24.04 LTS ISO in live mode and test it on your hardware before upgrade" - No, shame on me, but unfortunately I didn't do it :(. Updated from 20.04 to 22.04 was completed smoothly and I didn't expect any issues in this case :(

In the end, I reinstalled Kubuntu from scratch, and this temporarily resolved my issue: the OS started booting correctly. Then I started reinstalling applications and reconfiguring the system (very basic things, such as pairing Bluetooth devices and adding keyboard layouts), and after this, the OS stopped loading again. The problem was that I didn't have any logs on screen because of the 'quiet' and 'splash' options in the grub configuration. I removed them, and after that, the system started loading correctly again. It sounds mysterious and doesn't reveal the root cause of my problem, but it worked for me.

Glad it is working for you but this is not an answer that anyone can use.
